# Loose coupling in c#

Tags: dependency-injection, loose-coupling

Is *dependency injection* is the only way to achieve loose coupling in c#
?? I have been going through injection (DI), to solve the tight coupling, I found DI as one solution for that ! Buy I'm looking for other solutions even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is a bit abstract. you first need to define your problem.
But, in order to write a loosely coupled, you'll need to use abstractions and not implementations (so you can inherit and override whatever you want) and inject the abstractions with dependency injection to your class/methods.

that way you are not coupled to the specific implementation of the code and whoever wants can just implement the interface and pass it to the class/method.